# how to encode many categorical columns at the same time

Tags: python, pandas, categorical-data

Basically the title says it all.

When you have many columns that are currently in string format but you wish to encode categorically, how can you do it at the same time?

The method for each column I use is:

```
df["column1"]=pd.Categoric(df["column1"]).codes
```

Also tried `OrdinalEncoder` but I found it too picky: it doesn't work if there's `nan` and it also doesn't work if I input `0` instead of the `nan`.

Asking this question because I haven't found anything remotely close to an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an online tutorial for different ways of categorical encoding.

https://machinelearningmastery.com/how-to-prepare-categorical-data-for-deep-learning-in-python/